# How to get the two points of a line in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a component (link to `Test` class) which contain one line in it, and I put one point of this line to (0, 0).

Then drag it to Flash(fla), and get its `Shape` in AS3 like:

```
// in Test.as
// assume that the movie clip only contain one line.
var line:Shape = Shape(getChildAt(0));
```

And I can get one point of this line which is `x` and `y` of var `line`. But how to get another point of this line?

Edit:
Ignore component stuff above, here has another question but I guess it pretty much the same as the question above:

Draw a line from (0, 0) to (10, 10) and draw another line from (10, 0) to (0, 10), how to get those lines of two-point form in AS3?

If I access them as `Shape` then I get two similar shapes which have same `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` values. Does AS3 has some way to access line as a *REAL* line not just a shape? or does it has any way I can calculate it out?

Comment: thanks for point it out. I just update my question wish it's clearer than before.   :)

Comment: "Does AS3 has some way to access line as a REAL line not just a shape?"  There is no Line class in AS3.  What do you want to do with the line?  Change it?  Move it?  That would help us understand better the proper approach.

Comment: I wanna use a line as path of map, and put it into a component which link to my as class, that I can easily change the weight and type of that path, and also easily change its origin and destination.

Comment: More details:  I wanna use a line as path of map, and put it into a component which link to my AS class, that I can easily change the weight and type of that path by using Inspectable tag, and also easily change its origin and destination in Flash. But that's not easy to access the origin and destination points in AS, this disturb a lot, I have to use a additional (maybe useless) property "quadrant" to finger out the line in which quadrant (assume its origin point at 0,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a nice tricky way to do this eventually.

Here we go:

1. create a symbol and draw a line from origin point (0, 0) to (x, 0)
2. link this symbol to your source code, let's call `Line`.
3. drag this symbol to stage, and rotate, scale it if need.
4. in code `Line`:

   ```
   var v:Point = new Point(getBounds(this).right, 0);
   v = localToGlobal(v);
   ```

   then (x, y) and (v.x, v.y) can represent this line.

Answer (score 0):

The Shape class in AS3 is not intended to contain points that make up a shape. Rather its the most bare-bone display object you can create which has a graphics object (no mouse event dispatching, can't contain display objects, etc). Its name often gives the impression its more, but it isn't. Whatever gets represented by your draw calls is not accessible from the shape... or in general from any display object in AS3.

The width and height x, and y are just the display objects properties, which are based on the bounds of it. If you want to represent individual points, your going to have to create your own structure of points which ends up getting used to make draw calls visualize it later.

if you end up storing the points and then having each shape draw them, and wish to then be able to scale or translate the individual shapes and want to have the points in a coordinate space other then that local shape, DisplayObject's localToGlobal and globalToLocal may be of use to you.

```
var local:Point = new Point(10, 10);
var global:Point = someShape.localToGlobal(localPoint);
var inNewCoord:Point = parentContainer.globalToLocal(globalPoint)
```

If you really need to find this vector data... you may want to check this post out:
http://wahlers.com.br/claus/blog/hacking-swf-1-shapes-in-flash/

however that involves actually parsing the byte data of a swf.

Comment: "If you want to represent individual points, your going to have to create your own structure of points which ends up getting used to make draw calls visualize it later"
This is what I need partly, could you describe with more details? Any structure that I can draw it in Flash and still get it (represent as a line) in AS3

Comment: When you say draw it in flash, do you mean with the flash ide drawing tools? If so I'm fairly confident you won't get what you want, and even if you managed to... it would probably be easier for you to make a swf which allowed you create and remove points to draw, and saved those points in the format most convenient. If you needed this tool to exist in the editor, you may be able to make it into a component later. May I ask for more information as to what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, I just wanna use line as component with some "inspectable" properties. Then I can use it (and node component) to assemble a map in Flash(CS4) for pathfinding in AS3. As path data of map, I need to access those lines with two-point form. Actually there's a dirty way to do that, in line component I reflected (by using Inspectable tag) a quadrant property so I can calculate the two points of line. But I think it's just somehow awkward.